# Searching in eclipse always fails first time, always succeeds seconds time with identical search string

Tags: eclipse

I've noticed that if I search for something in Eclipse (using it for Android development thus has the Android plugin) then the first time I search for a search string it always says there are no matches, but if I immediatly report the same search, then there are matches.

Using: Search/Search/File Search - then enter something in the "Containing text:" box (Case sensitvie is off, regular expression is off, file name patterns are *.*).
It will report "'search term' - 0 matches in workspace(*.*).

If I search again it will fail again *unless* I retype the search term or copy and paste it (no, I'm not mistyping it, if I enter it the first time when it fails, then copy and paste the term for the next successful search its obviously an identical search term).

This happens 100% of the time. Why is it doing this? Its really bugging me, when I search something I have to enter it twice it in order to get the results which is irritating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the search scope at the bottom and make sure the correct one is selected:

Workspace
       Selected resources
       Enclosing projects
       Working set

If you have a project highlighted in your workspace when you open the search dialog, it will default to the selected resource, otherwise it will default to the workspace, so that may be why you are seeing different results the second time around.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, however I don't have a project highlighted in the package explorer when it does this. It defauls to workspace, playing around with others doesn't seem to make a difference but will try some more